# "Stale element exception" when trying to validate multiple elements in a Dynamic webtable

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testing, automated-tests

Scenario:

1. I need to handle webtable-1 and identify the links and click on the first link.
2. which takes you to audit page, there another webtable is present in which I need to check each row and validate the desired values are present or not (Note: In this i need to validate multiple values).
3. We the elements are present break from the condition and move back to webtable-1 and click on another link and do the same as step-2.
4. This i need to do for all the links present in the webtable-1.

Tried to fetch click on the links present in the Webtable-1 and able to navigate to audit page and tried to validate the values by using if condition, here i need to validate multiple values but with if condition am able to validate only one value.

- Please help me with code how to validate multiple values in each row.

Again moved back to table-1 by clicking on a button to move back and clicked on another link and trying to validate the values in the audit page getting stale element exception.

- Please help me with this stale element exception. Tried so much but not able to figure it out.

Here is my code

List noOfTrans = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[contains(@id, 'resultant')]//td[1]"));
System.out.println(noOfTrans.size());

```
    for (int k = 0; k < noOfTrans.size(); k++) {
        if (k > 0) {
            driver.findElement(By.id("Histbtn")).click();
            System.out.println("Clicked Second transaction");
        }

        String value = noOfTrans.get(k).getText();
        System.out.println(value);
        noOfTrans.get(k).click();
        System.out.println("Clicked first transaction");
        Thread.sleep(4000);

        /* Audit table data. */

        WebElement auditresultsTable = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='resultantAudit']//tbody"));
        List<WebElement> auditsresultsRows = auditresultsTable
                .findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='resultantAudit']//tbody//tr"));
        // int numberOfRows = auditsresultsRows.size();
        // System.out.println("Number Of Rows present in a table: " + numberOfRows);
        int rowCount = auditsresultsRows.size();
        System.out.println("Audit results: " + rowCount);

        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {// changed i = 1

            List<WebElement> auditsColumns = auditsresultsRows.get(i)
                    .findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='resultantAudit']//tbody//tr//td"));
            int columnCount = auditsColumns.size();

            for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {

                String cellText = auditsColumns.get(j).getText();

                if (cellText.equals("CLUSTER:RIVER")) {
                    System.out.println("Status of CLUSTER:RIVER: " + auditsColumns.get(3).getText());
                    /*
                    here am tryint to print in the same row status of the element is showing as S or Not
                    */
```

break;
}

```
            if (cellText.equals("Outbound:LUMO")){
                System.out.println("Status of Outbound:LUMO: " + auditsColumns.get(3).getText());
                
            }
                

            }
            

        }
        
    }
```

//driver.quit();

```
}
```

Please help me with this I got stuck with this from fast few days.

Reference sample : https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/recruitment/viewCandidates

1. Navigate to recruitment under records table select any row and click on the Eye icon.
2. Which navigate to Candidates.
3. Need to validate the Vacancy table check for the Vacancy and status.

this I need to verify multiple times.